# How should I handle the pushsubscriptionchange event?

Tags: web-push, progressive-web-apps

[According to the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/push-api/#the-pushsubscriptionchange-event), a `pushsubscriptionchange` event indicates that "a push subscription has been invalidated, or will soon be invalidated." What are the best practices for handling this event?

Answer (score 5):

1. **Process the re-subscription entirely within the service worker.** There may be no client (i.e. open pages) associated with the service worker at the point the event is fired--do not use `postMessage()` to trigger a re-subscription from the client.
2. **Implementations are likely to honour the old subscription for a period of time (probably days).** Whilst the spec makes no such guarantee, it is likely that implementations will support both old and new keys for some time to reduce/eliminate the chance of messages being dropped because one of the clients or servers involved hasn't received the "new" key.
3. **As of April 2016 neither Chrome nor Firefox fires this event.** However, since it's in the spec, to ensure users continue to receive messages, you should make sure you handle it correctly.

Comment: Do you know if chrome implements the event? I can't get to trigger it. I'm losing subscriptions every day, and I think this is because this event is not triggered. @mjs

Answer (score 4):

You can find here a fully detailed explanation of handling `pushsubscriptionchange` event with some pitfalls you will have to deal with. Like:

- Push subscription change is not currently implemented in Chrome.
- `PushSubscriptionChangeEvent` is always null. You won't have the `oldSubscription` to use if you want to replace it in the server.

[How to handle WebPush API PushSubscriptionChange event in modern browsers](https://medium.com/@madridserginho/how-to-handle-webpush-api-pushsubscriptionchange-event-in-modern-browsers-6e47840d756f)

Comment: how would I test for whether PushSubscriptionChangeEvent is defined *before* registering my service worker, in my normal javascript? In the future when the spec is implemented everywhere, I'd like to only bother with push subscriptions and service workers if this is defined, and just telling the user to update their browser if it’s not.

Comment: Hi Serginho, Is it still null ? ( I mean oldsubscription ? ) and does chrome still not support pushsubscriptionchange event?

Comment: I havent check last versions of chrome. 4months ago It was null. I would say nothing changed

Comment: Is still a better solution available or update as for 2021? The big advantage of these push notifications is to notify the user even if s/he doesn't access the app. But the best we can have this Serginho's workaround.